# While working in animation (angular 13). I get a console error

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

**TS FILE**

```js
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, ElementRef, Injectable, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from '../../shared-service/shared-services.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      // ...
      state('open', style({
        height: '200px',
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: 0.8,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      })),
      transition('open => closed', [
        animate('1s')
      ]),
      transition('closed => open', [
        animate('0.5s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

**HTML CODE**

```html
     <div [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="open-close-container">
            <p>The box is now {{ isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed' }}!</p>
          </div>
```

> Error: src/app/core/sharedComponenet/sidebar/sidebar.component.html:10:34 - error TS2339: Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.

Comment: Can you post your class for your sidebar component? Do you have an isOpen property on it?

Comment: the error say you must declare a variable isOpen in your .ts: `isOpen:string='Open';`